# DOMException: The user aborted a request (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

In my code there is a `timeout` so that if in 25 seconds there is no response to my request, the request is cancelled with `controller.abort()` and shows a Sweetalert2 informing the users a "server timeout". And also I have another Sweetalert for errors in general. So that the users know that something is failing.

**The problem** is that it does **NOT show the Sweetalert of the timeout** (although it does cancel the request). And instead it shows the general error Sweetalert.

In the console I get the error `DOMException: The user aborted a request` but I can't solve it. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
const envSoli = async () => {
  try {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      Swal.fire({
        //error timeout
        //custom function translate
        text: translate("text1"),
        icon: "info",
        buttonsStyling: false,
        confirmButtonText: translate("confirmbtn"),
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: "btn btn-info",
        },
        //refresh on ok click button
      }).then(function () {
        location.reload();
      });
       //controller.abort(), the idea is abort a request
       //after show the sweetalert
      controller.abort();
    }, 20 * 1000); // 20 sec
    let peticion = await fetch("data.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      cache: "no-cache",
      signal: signal,
    });
    clearTimeout(timeId);
    let oreen = await peticion.json();

    switch (oreen.enviando) {
      case -1:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 1:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 2:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
        nieva++;
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_dieUp();
        break;

      case 3:
        chenille++;
        document.getElementById("div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
        tvmit_liveUp();
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        break;
    }

    OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    Swal.fire({
      text: translate("text2"),
      icon: "question",
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonText: translate("confirmbtn"),
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      allowEscapeKey: false,
      customClass: {
        confirmButton: "btn btn-primary",
      },
      //refresh again on button click
    }).then(function () {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
};
envSoli();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error came from the aborted request by `controller.abort()`, I suggest you catch the error to not stop execution.

```
      try {
        controller.abort();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
      Swal.fire({
        //error timeout
        //custom function translate, to auto translate the text
        text: translate("text1"),
        icon: "info",
        buttonsStyling: false,
        confirmButtonText: translate("confirmbtn"),
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        customClass: {
          confirmButton: "btn btn-info",
        },
        //refresh on ok click button
      }).then(function () {
        location.reload();
      });
```

Comment: One question, but isn't there a way to have both sweetalerts?

Comment: What do you mean by "both sweetalerts"?

Comment: Yes, I would like to show the timeout sweetalert (when the server is on timeout) and also show the other sweetalert that was previously in the catch. I would like to keep showing it in case there is some kind of error and not only in console